# How to apply css and js files to part of the html file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a very large `HTML` file with many sections in the file.

I need to use some styles library downloaded from the internet and apply it to a specific section of my HTML file.

When I include files `(.css, .js)` in my `<head>` tag styles getting applied to all my `HTML` as expected.

Is there any way I can restrict my styles to part of my `HTML` page and leaving the other sections as it is so that it can consume the default styles?

Thanks for the help.

ps: since styles in files and many I can't add them directly in my style attribute.

Comment: You can always overwrite that styling with your own CSS resets. E.g. `.content{color: red;} .my-styles .content {color: initial}`. With JS - that completely depends on what it's doing. If it acts on selectors - change selectors.

Comment: Depending on details there may be different approaches to your problem. For example, you can manually alter this css files and add additional class name to selectors. If you use build tools that rely on postcss, you can make a plugin that will do this for you automatically, but complexity of said plugin will depend on your css.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using new style classes and ids for the html you want to style.
Then you can include those classes and ids in last css file added on page. It will override the previous classes styles.

eg.

```
<div class="older-class myNewClass">Text</div
```

Answer (score 0):

Styles can be restricted via selectors on CSS side: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Also, you can use inline styles in HTML.